# HTML5 with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

We are plannig a new project and we want to use ASP.NET in conjunction with the MVC pattern. We want also have acces to new features includes in HTML5. But we do not found  many information or people going in the same direction.

Is there some kind of contradiction with ASP.NET MVC with HTML5 or the subject is so trivial that just a few people are talking about it ?

(Question reformulated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC generates valid HTML5 just fine, and you're perfectly OK to use it in your apps.  ASP.NET MVC is the templating, and back-end that generates HTML, including HTML5 and all the new features of it!

Answer (score 0):

Even if ASP.NET MVC didn't generate valid HTML5 (which it does), you can [use templates](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx) to output your HTML exactly how you want to.